# Working with PDO namespaces

Tags: php, pdo

right now i'm working with and new project and while I'm creating a Class which has a namespace called User and when i try to make a query with the PDO::prepare i get an error. Here is my code:

```
public function Exists() {

                $Query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = :newEmail";

                    $sqlQuery = $this->Connection->PDO::preapre($Query);

                        $sqlQuery->bindValue(":newEmail", $this->Email);

                            $sqlQuery->execute();

                                if (!$sqlQuery->rowCount()) {

                                    return true;

                                } else {

                                    throw new \Exception("Email already registered.");

                                }

            }
```

I know i can sole this using use \PDO at the beginning of the file, but my question is if where i have in my code PDO::prepare, which is wrong, there is another way of typing it or whatelse. Thanks!

Comment: `prepare()` is a method of the connection object. Assuming `$this->Connection` is already a PDO object, you should not have the `PDO` class there and just use `$this->Connection->prepare($Query)`  (note you misspelled it as `preapre()` also)

Comment: Right now i feeling the most stupid person in this world, lol, it was misspelled. Well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Connection->PDO::preapre($Query);
```

Should be

```
$this->Connection->PDO::prepare($Query);
```

Comment: Actually, doing this without the Connection? It won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it for future reference for other users.